Reuse overloaded method in python class with most parameters
I have LCD class which is run by micropython on raspberry pi pico which i initialise like this:
class Lcd:
    def __init__(self, width, height, channel, sdaPin, sclPin, contrast):
        from time import sleep
        from machine import Pin, I2C
        from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
        self.contrast = contrast
        self.sleep = sleep
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.channel = channel
        self.i2cLCD = I2C(self.channel, sda=Pin(sdaPin), scl=Pin(sclPin), freq=400000)
        self.dsp=SSD1306_I2C(self.width,self.height,self.i2cLCD)

And initialise an object in main program like this:
lcd = Lcd(128,64,1,26, 27, 1)

However i have a problem, which i cannot find answer for in Python (micropython). Eg. In java you can overload methods like this without any problem:
double calculateBalance(double income, double expenses){
        return income - expenses;
    }
    
    double calculateBalance(){
        return this.calculateBalance(100, 80); // only as example, it can be some default params
    }

so i can call either of these methods on an object, with or without params. Without params i default to something, and with params i can specify them. Thus saving code by reusing method with most params. However, when i try to do simmilar thing in python on my previously shown LCD class's .text() method:
def text(self, txt, startXPx, startYPx , colsCount, rowsCount, dsp):
        # some logic for this method to display text on LCD
        self.dsp.show()
    
    def text(self, txt):
        # just calling upper method with default params
        self.text( txt, 0, 0, self.width/8, self.height/10, 1)

and when that calling method:
lcd.text('my text')

i get error:
MPY: soft reboot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 60, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 50, in text
TypeError: function takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given

Question is why it gives me error and how can i achieve this?

Also see this question and answers mentioning @overload and @singledispatch.

In Python, instead of setting default parameter values by creating multiple methods with the same name, you can simply specify the default values in the one method declaration. These default values are evaluated when you declare the method, not when you call it, however, so in some cases (e.g. colsCount and rowsCount), you might have to set the default value to None and handle that in the method body:
def text(self, txt, startXPx = 0, startYPx = 0, colsCount = None, rowsCount = None, dsp = 1):
    if colsCount is None:
        colsCount = self.width/8
    if rowsCount is None:
        rowsCount = self.height/10
    # some logic for this method to display text on LCD
    self.dsp.show()


It seems that it handles default params problem, but it may raise different problems later, e.g. i may later need another method, witch will need only some of these params of the big method, and this method may have different logic inside, but also at the end call that big method with all params as well, which i would like to set differently depending on that mid-method specific logic. I am curious if python can actually reference other overloaded methods with the same name.

No, Python doesn't support two methods with the same name, even if their parameters are different. From a readability point of view, I think that's a good thing — if the logic inside two methods is different, they should probably have different names that make clear what those differences are.

Actually, I now read @simon's comment on the main post. It seems there are ways to do it, but it's generally not the Pythonic way.

Now when i read more, maybe it is possible to implement something with *args wildcard? But then i am confused of how at the same time implement default values of some of these *args. Maybe in the body of a method set them, if they are None type?

You could do that, but then the same method body would still be executed no matter what arguments you passed in to it. As I say, it looks like the question @simon linked has some answers that do what you want. However, I would advise you to think about whether doing so actually makes your code more readable, or whether it just makes it more Java-like.

I am not sure if code flexibility, and giving up power of the programming language should be sacrificed for the sake of code readabity. Imho readability then looses it's point, when you cannot simply achieve same things with more simplicity.
